# how to divide 2 times with specific time duration

Tags: php

have 2 times `$dayFrom = 10:00:00;` and `$dayTo = 12:00:00` i want to divide it in 15 minutes time duration.

**Expected Result**

`10:00:00, 10:15:00, 10:30:00, 10:45:00 and so on`

Looking for help

Comment: `DateTime` and `DateInterval` come to mind

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeArray = array();
$startTime  = new \DateTime("2010-01-01 10:00:00");
$endTime    = new \DateTime("2010-01-01 12:00:00");
while($startTime < $endTime) {
    $timeArray[] = $startTime->format('H:i:s');
    $startTime->add(new \DateInterval('PT 15 M'));
}
echo implode(",",$timeArray);
```

Here You can go with this code. It will be helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this -

```
$dayFrom = strtotime('10:00:00');
$dayTo = strtotime('12:00:00');

while($dayFrom <= $dayTo) {
   echo date('H:i:s', $dayFrom);
   $dayFrom= strtotime('+ 15 MINUTES', $dayFrom);
}
```

**Output**

```
10:00:00
10:15:00
10:30:00
10:45:00
11:00:00
11:15:00
11:30:00
11:45:00
12:00:00
```

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on a theme - using DateInterval.

```
$df='H:i';
$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$interval=new DateInterval('PT15M');

$ts=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('10.00am') );
$tf=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('12.00pm') );

$start=new DateTime( $ts, $timezone );
$end=new DateTime( $tf, $timezone );

while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end ){
    echo $start->format( $df ).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dayFrom = "10:00:00";
$dayTo = "12:00:00";
while($endTime<$dayTo){   
$endTime = strtotime($dayFrom) + 900;
echo date('h:i:s', $endTime);
}
```

Try this.